# How can I plot [sin(nx)/sin(x)]^2?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a function that includes a [sin(n x)/sin(x)]^2 term, however all I'm getting back is an array of nan and this warning:

```
invalid value encountered in divide
  return (np.sin(n * alpha * x * np.pi) / np.sin(alpha * x * np.pi))**2
```

This is my function:

```
def fun(x):
    return (np.sinc(beta * x)**2) * (np.sin(n * alpha * x * np.pi) / np.sin(alpha * x * np.pi))**2
```

I get the same problems if I simplify the function to just be `(np.sin(n * x) / np.sin(x))**2`.

`x` is an 1D np.array of 30000 elements ranging from .001 to 30 in steps of .001 and alpha is ~0.452

I tried making a simple example with `linspace`, but now it's working fine.

I'm not sure why I can't recreate this with different data points, but this solution worked decently:

```
return (np.sin(n * x[np.sin(x) != 0]) / np.sin(x[np.sin(x) != 0]))**2
```

Comment: What value are you passing to `fun`? For example, if I call it with an array `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`, I get 1 NaN in the result (as expected for the singularity at x=0), but the other values in the result are non-NaN as expected.

Comment: (and what's the value of `alpha`?)

Comment: This is weird, I just can't replicate this at all. Can you show a minimal reproducible example, i.e. a piece of code which defines all the constants, creates the input, and produces the output?

Answer (score 2):

The reason, you are getting the error, is because you divided by zero. That is trivial. As you know that your function is well defined and continuous at these critical points (I assume you did the mathetmatical proof on your own), you can play a little trick to get the plot, which is what you asked for:

Plot only points, where `sin(x)!=0`.
For example, the following snippet will recreate you error:

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 1000)

for n in range(10):
    y = (sin(n * x) / sin(x))**2
    plot(x,y,label=n)    
legend()
```

while the following won't, because x is slightly different from pi and zero:

```
x = linspace(-3.1415, 3.1415, 1000)
for n in range(10):
    y = (sin(n * x) / sin(x))**2
    plot(x,y,label=n)

legend()
```

I get the following output:

[image]